# RegEx with grep for Linux

Tags: regex, linux, grep

Need some help at the command line running CentOS, but ultimately will be used on a Linux build.  I've looked on the forum here and have tried a RegEx builder tool and I know the sytax for regex is right, but obviously it's not working.

options with the following have been tried in various combinations, not all together. ioFE

`3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
ping -c 3 192.168.0.113 | grep '(?<=received,)(.*)(?=,)'`

I feel this should work, but not sure what is missing given what I know about regex.  What am I doing wrong?

Updated.  Two answers provided that both work:

`ping -c 3 192.168.0.113 | grep -Po '(?<=received,)(.*)(?=,)'`

`ping -c 3 192.168.0.113 | grep -Po 'received,\K[^,]+'`

Comment: I would not use such a strict expression, especially if it requires a very specific RE syntax. If you want to do more with the ping output it might be a good idea to use fping, (and extracting the actual values would use sed or awk.

Comment: We're using the output to identify whether or not a server is responding to ping.  If the value is not 0% packet loss, we escalate the event to the server team.  so if the value is 100%, 25%, 66%, etc., we will send to the server team.  If we get 0%, we run another test against a monitor that is on the server, which is a whole other command that has been fully and successfully tested.

Comment: Thanks for the comment by the way. If we find it's not working, I will look at fping for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -P '(?<=received,)(.*)(?=,)'
```

You will have to enable `-P` mode for that regex to work.Your regex is correct.[See here](https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/6)

Comment: Thank you as well!  Really appreciate the input and knowledge on this board! Also, I am using RegExBuilder and it showed the same thing which is why I was really bothered by the fact that it didn't work. :)

Comment: I did not or if I did, it was not intentional.  Sorry if somehow I did that.

Comment: @JonT its not you.Its some anonymous person. :)

Comment: I guess some down voted this, since it does not work.  It miss a `'` at the end of it.  Also posting output of your command is helpful for other. Eks output of `ping -c 8.8.8.8 | grep -P '(?<=received,)(.*)(?=,)'`